# Azure Function v4 not logging to Application Insights deployed to Azure, but logging locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a simple Azure function v4, implemented on C#.
Have a simple call:

```
_logger.LogTrace(
      new LogTraceParameter
           {
                  Message = "Message to be logged",
                  FunctionName = context.FunctionName,
                  SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Information,
                  Category = Category.Request,
                  SubCategory = SubCategory.Incoming
              });
```

That functionality works fine locally and logs to App Insights. But doesn't work when is deployed to portal.
Host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
```

As well I checked Instrumetal key. Tried to remove "excludedTypes": "Request", or adding "Function.FunctionName": "Trace" to host.json file. It hasn't helped.
Where could be an error?

Comment: You might want to consider opening a support case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Configuration on azure portal of app insights?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Can you change "_logger.LogTrace" to "_logger.LogError", to rule out if the issue is related to the severity?
For regular asp.net core, only Warning or above is collected by default, not sure if this is affecting you...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcore6#ilogger-logs